# MySQL combining two where operators WHERE row LIKE '%$search%' AND WHERE NOT row='$id'

Tags: mysql, select, search, where-clause, sql-like

`SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE column_name LIKE '%$search%' AND WHERE NOT column_name='$id';`

I want to select all the results from my database that are like my search term, but exclude the row that is equal to my php variable $id.

Is it possible to do this in a MySQL query?

Comment: A literal string `'string'` does not translate variables to their value, so this would not work unless you use `"double quoted strings"`. But don't do that either, use prepared statements by either using `PDO` or `MySQLi`.

Comment: my sql variable is using mysqli

$sql = "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE column_name LIKE '%$search%' AND WHERE NOT column_name='$id'";

Comment: Exactly, you're not using prepared statements. Your database is wide open to an attack if you don't handle your data correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the all the conditions inside a single `WHERE` block and use conditional operators like `AND/OR/NOT` to combine them

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE `row` LIKE '%$search%' AND 
      `row` <> '$id';
```

Also, please learn to use [Prepared Statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: ```$sql = "SELECT * FROM userprofile WHERE userUid LIKE '%$search%' OR profileFirstName LIKE '%$search%' OR profileLastName LIKE '%$search%' OR profileStatus LIKE '%$search%' OR profileGender LIKE '%$search%' NOT userUid <> '$id'";```

This is still not working

Comment: remove `not` before `userUid`. use `and useruid <> '$id'`

Comment: The code has no errors then, but it is still not excluding the rows in the `userUid` column that are equal to php variable $id.

Comment: @Hurly please use proper parentheses around conditions. put all the `or` conditions inside one pair of brackets and `and useruid <>` outside that

Comment: Also @Madhur Bhaiya i am using Prepared Statements. ;)

I only show the code for my mysql query. Because that is what is not working.

Comment: @Hurly does putting parentheses properly work now ? You can read about operator precedence to understand the importance of parentheses (brackets).

Comment: this code gives no error, but is still not filtering out the data equal to php variable $id.
 ```$sql = "SELECT * FROM userprofile WHERE userUid LIKE '%$search%' OR (profileFirstName LIKE '%$search%') OR (profileLastName LIKE '%$search%') OR (profileStatus LIKE '%$search%') OR (profileGender LIKE '%$search%') AND userUid <> '$id'";```

Comment: @Hurly do this: `$sql = "SELECT * FROM userprofile WHERE (userUid LIKE '%$search%' OR profileFirstName LIKE '%$search%' OR profileLastName LIKE '%$search%' OR profileStatus LIKE '%$search%' OR profileGender LIKE '%$search%') AND userUid <> '$id'"`

Comment: thankyou. That code is working without error and is the solution to my question.